# How we can distinguish between this Windows version 2008/XP/7/2003 with PHP

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, user-agent

As we know.. it's easy to detect visitor operating system and version by simple php code

```
function getOS($userAgent) {
  // Create list of operating systems with operating system name as array key
 $oses = array (
  'iPhone' => '(iPhone)',
  'iPad' => 'iPad',
  'Android' => 'Android',
  'Windows 3.11' => 'Win16',
  'Windows 95' => '(Windows 95)|(Win95)|(Windows_95)', // Use regular expressions as value to identify operating system
  'Windows 98' => '(Windows 98)|(Win98)',
  'Windows 2000' => '(Windows NT 5.0)|(Windows 2000)',
  'Windows XP' => '(Windows NT 5.1)|(Windows XP)',
  'Windows Server 2003' => '(Windows NT 5.2)',
  'Windows Vista' => '(Windows NT 6.0)|(Windows Vista)',
  'Windows 7' => '(Windows NT 6.1)|(Windows 7)',
  'Windows NT 4.0' => '(Windows NT 4.0)|(WinNT4.0)|(WinNT)|(Windows NT)',
  'Windows ME' => 'Windows ME',
  'Open BSD'=>'OpenBSD',
  'Sun OS'=>'SunOS',
  'Linux'=>'(Linux)|(X11)',
  'Safari' => '(Safari)',
  'Macintosh'=>'(Mac_PowerPC)|(Macintosh)',
  'QNX'=>'QNX',
  'BeOS'=>'BeOS',
  'OS/2'=>'OS/2',
  'Search Bot'=>'(nuhk)|(Googlebot)|(Yammybot)|(Openbot)|(Slurp/cat)|(msnbot)|(ia_archiver)'
 );

 foreach($oses as $os=>$pattern){ // Loop through $oses array
    // Use regular expressions to check operating system type
  if(eregi($pattern, $userAgent)) { // Check if a value in $oses array matches current user agent.
   return $os; // Operating system was matched so return $oses key
  }
 }
 return 'Unknown'; // Cannot find operating system so return Unknown
}
```

But there is one problem , some windows have the same NT releases :

Windows server 2008/ windows Vista = NT 6.0

Windows server 2008 R2/ Windows7 = NT 6.1

Windows XP 64-bit Edition / Windows Server 2003 / Windows XP Professional x64 Edition/ Windows Server 2003 R2 = NT 5.2

You can see this here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT

How we can distinguish between this Windows version with php ?!

Answer (score 1):

There's actually quite easy way to do it. It involves [`get_browser`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function and [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp). You'll be able to write:

```
$browser = get_browser(user_agent...);
echo $browser->platform;
```

Just don't forget to check notes about this function on its page.

Comment: Thank you Ondrej Slintak. actually they have the same problem with windows server 2003/2008. check this http://browsers.garykeith.com/news-archives

Comment: Ouch, I didn't know about that.

Comment: That is ok...Thank you for your help :)

Comment: well, do you really think you'll have many visitors from windows server 2003 and 2008? It's it _that_ important?

Comment: I think that is impossible to find away for that :(